# Select dates between this monday and this friday

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a table with a date field (2013-07-11 = July 11th, 2013).

I need to select entries from the monday (the start of my week) of any given week until the end of that week.

I've seen queries that can grab rows whose date is 1 week ago, but I specifically need to grab rows that have a `date` field that occurs this week, regardless of what the current day of the week is.

I'm currently grabbing it in php using this, but I feel like there has to be a mysql method for calculating the beginning and end of this week:

```
$this_monday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('previous monday'));
$this_friday = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('this friday'));

$sql = "SELECT `date`, $sign FROM `horoscopes` 
    WHERE `date` >= '$this_monday' AND `date` <= '$this_friday'
    AND type = 'Daily'
    ORDER BY `date` ASC
";
```

And I'm pretty sure that on monday it will end up grabbing monday of last week, not monday.

from this data set I'd like to select the following:

```
+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 2013-07-12 |
| 2013-07-11 |
| 2013-07-10 |
| 2013-07-09 |
| 2013-07-17 |
| 2013-07-08 |
| 2013-07-05 |
+------------+
```

7-8, 7-9, 7-10, 7-11, 7-12 regardless of the day of the week.

Comment: why don't you use the week() function?

Comment: Because I didn't know about it until just now. I'll update my question with the answer instead of just deleting it in case it it useful for someone else. Thanks.

Comment: dont update the question, write your own answer below (and accept that). Then this question doesn't show up unanswered.

Comment: Thanks, just learned another thing.

Comment: thats the meaning ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just learned about the [WEEK() function in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)

```
SELECT `date` FROM horoscopes WHERE WEEK(`date`) = WEEK(NOW(), -1);
```

Comment: You should probably check the year matches as well.

Comment: @Kickstart Normally I'd agree with you, but they are just horoscopes after all :-)

Comment: Definitely will add the year to these as well.